# How to run ActiveMQ program in Java

Tags: activemq-classic

I have install ActiveMQ 5.5.1 in my `c:\programFiles\activemq\...` and from the command prompt I have installed it and set environment variable.

And I have also run it, and it is also running on `localhost`.

I have written a Java program in my eclipse editor, and I have added ActiveMQ library in project form that path.

Program: http://developers-blog.org/blog/default/2008/10/28/A-simple-ActiveMQ-example

But I am also confused. What is the use of that `c:\programFiles\activemq\...` installation? How do I use it?

I want to only to create my first ActiveMQ program through Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of ActiveMQ gives you everything you need to run the broker standalone by just running the activemq.bat under the bin directory. It's just a nice way of packaging the application as opposed to just giving you some jar files.
If you want to run the broker inside a Java program you just need to include the jars for the broker and you won't need to use the installation directory again.